# iTunes Connect Asking For New Icon - 1024 x 1024

Tags: app-store, icons, app-store-connect

I've just went to push an update of my iOS app to iTuneConnect and it's suddenly asking for a 1024x1024 icon. This isn't a problem and I've uploaded a big icon however the one I've uploaded is non-rounded corners and not gloss whereas the old one was.

The view in iTuneConnect looks like this,

[Linky to screenshot http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg100/scaled.php?server=100&filename=screenshot20120927at051.png&res=landing](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg100/scaled.php?server=100&filename=screenshot20120927at051.png&res=landing)

Will after I click submit or it's approved or basically anytime before it goes live on the app store will it become rendered and glossed like the first time round.

Comment: 1024x1024px icon? That's pretty huge.

Comment: Tell me about it. But since when has anything Apple done ever really made sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it will but it can take up to 30 minutes or so from uploading. Just checked and it's been rendered.